# Windows 10 sdk installer crashing "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID"

Tags: sdk, crash, windows-10, crash-reports

When I try to install the Windows 10 SDK It always crashes with the final entry in the log file being "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID" Logfile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PSVJRmbmBhV6NAYbP182TsPGhHRol14J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Exception: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} this GUID is [this class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.setup.interop.setupconfiguration?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) located in Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core.dll. do you have this file on your system?

Comment: Huge thanks, the dll was missing for whatever Reason but got it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44909 and It worked.

Comment: I posted it as answer so that you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: I think this answer my current issue (can download but not install the debugger through the Win 10 DSK). However, I can't figure out where that log is on my system. Could anyone please tell me where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the log file I see this error:

> Exception: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following
>   error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

So the COM compoment with CLSID `{177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D}` is missing. Searching for the CLSID `{177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D}` shows [this page about a class SetupConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.setup.interop.setupconfiguration?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) which is located in `Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core.dll` an the `Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core.dll` is missing on your system.